# Laravel 5.1 How to check for the presence a file in a directory?

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.1

I have a form in which users can upload files to the upload folder. In the controller I need to check if the file already exists in the upload directory and if it exists not to allow uploading the same file twice.
How can I check this?

Comment: have you tried if(file_exists($filePath)) then do not allow uploading of the file again? Possibly just redirect with an error message so that the user knows the reason for the denial of upload?

Comment: @Cameeob2003 Yes, I tried this in my controller: 
            $filename='/public/uploads/'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
            if(file_exists($filename)){
                return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['  File already exists.']);
            }
        }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the problem it's that you are checking if the file exists in the root folder of the server.

Try this

```
    if (file_exists(public_path('uploads/'.$file->getClientOriginalName()))) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([' File already exists.']);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your files are stored in the "public" folder, then try this :

```
\File::exists(public_path().'\\uploads\\'.$file->getClientOriginalName())
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to mention  **use File** at top of the page in your controller

```
$imagepath = "1.jpg";

$directoryPath = 'user_img/'.$imagepath;

if(File::exists($directoryPath)){
    //echo "n exist"; die();
} else {  echo "not exists";   }
```